# Connection management in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP 7.2 on a website hosted on Amazon. I have a code similar to this one that writes a record in the MongoDB:

**Database connection class:**

```
class Database {
    private static $instance;
    private $managerMongoDB;
    
    private function __construct() {
        #Singleton private constructor
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function writeMongo($collection, $record) {
        if (empty($this->managerMongoDB)) {
            $this->managerMongoDB = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(DB_MONGO_HOST ? DB_MONGO_HOST : null);
        }
        $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
        $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
        $bulk->insert($record);
        try {
            $result = $this->managerMongoDB->executeBulkWrite(
                DB_MONGO_NAME . '.' . $collection, $bulk, $writeConcern
            );
        } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $e) {
            // Not important
        } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
            // Not important
        }
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }
}
```

**Execution:**

```
Database::getInstance()->writeMongo($tableName, $dataForMongo);
```

The script is working as intended and the records are added in MongoDB.

The problem is that connections are not being closed at all and once there are 500 inserts (500 is the limit of connections in MongoDB on our server) it stops working. If we restart php-fpm the connections are also reset and we can insert 500 more records.

The connection is reused during the request, but we have requests coming from 100s of actual customers.

As far as I can see there is no way to manually close the connections. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there some configuration that needs to be done on the driver? I tried setting **socketTimeoutMS=1000&wTimeoutMS=1000&connectTimeoutMS=1000** in the connection string but the connections keep staying alive.

Comment: Instead of creating new connections when your functions are executed, create one single connection that you reuse during that request.  Just pass the connection to the function as an argument (dependency injection) and use that.

Comment: I am reusing the connection for the same request. This is just not present in the sample code above. The problem is that we have 100s of real users and each of them generates a single insert in the database. Once we have 500 users (not concurrent) all 500 connections are exhausted.

Comment: Please post your actual code. It's literally impossible to know what you're _actually_ doing (and find potential logic issues etc) if we only get to see examples that has different logic than the real code. This is a good example of that; you have issues with too many connections and posted example code that could explain it.

Comment: Updated as requested. I use a class as Singleton and keep the connection during the request. The problem comes when there are many inserts coming from separate requests. As mentioned - currently in the application we have only a single insert per HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a client instance every time the function is invoked, and never closing it, which would produce the behavior you are seeing.

If you want to create the client instance in the function, close it in the same function.

Alternatively create the client instance once for the entire script and use the same instance in all of the operations done by that script.